# One of my computer has unstable connections and ping

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, proxy, ping

So mine and my partners computer both connect to a wireless network. My partners connection are doing fine. My connections are very unstable.

Both computer need to go through the same wifi repeater

So computer -> 192.168.10.253 -> 192.168.1.1 -> google.com

These are the screenshot of my computer

[image]

The ping is 500 ms. It's not always like this. I used to connect just fine. I used to play games with low pings.

Sometimes I got a strange message as if my computer should connect through a proxy

[image]

It seems that as if I am connecting through proxy 216.108.225.199:60099

I have no idea what IP is that. Virus? Is my computer hijacked?

Note: I can access some sites but not google

Comment: You are currently using a proxy.  Disable the proxy by editing the adaptors configuration.  Malware has been known to configure a proxy on a Windows installation.

Comment: [216.108.225.199](http://www.iplocationtools.com/216.108.225.199.html) seems pretty standard.

Comment: I am not using proxy. I am not supposed to at least.

Comment: How do I check if all my internet connection go through proxies or not?

Comment: You have verified that?  It is worth pointing out that Teamviewer has a feature where you can install a proxy.  The fact you are using Teamviewer indicates to me, you actually are, using that feature

Comment: **Correction**: Teamviewer has the capability to enable a TeamViewer VPN.  The proxy might be something else.  Verify neither a proxy nor the VPN is being used.

Answer (score 1):

The latency that you are seeing when pinging your next hop (192.168.10.253) is ludicrously high.

Aside from your partner's device, can you test the ping latency from another device connected to that AP? If it only seems slow for yourself you will need to investigate your Computer. Try connecting via LAN and run the same ping tests. That should point you in the direction whether this could be an issue with your WLAN adapter.

Regarding Teamviewer, I believe the TeamViewer client will try to use the system proxy settings by default (if any are configured). The first place to check will be Control Panel > Internet Options > Connections tab > LAN Settings. If Proxy details have been configured in this section and you are not expecting them to be, feel free to remove. If no proxy settings are configured, look within the TeamViewer network settings to see if a Proxy has been manually configured for whatever reason.

Although it is possible that malicious software has confirmed proxy settings on your PC, this *should* not impact ICMP (ping) traffic as only web traffic is proxied.